# Xcode 6.4 Organizer Crashes not displaying crashes

Tags: xcode

I know I have app crashes in itunesconnect App Analytics but they don't display in Xcode Organizer Crashes.  The Version and Build menu also doesn't display.  Prior versions and builds, and associated crashes used to display a couple weeks ago, but no longer.  I made sure the 'Include app symbols...' was checked in Submit to App Store.  The Organizer Archives does display all the archives.  I reinstalled Xcode to try and fix the issue, but no change.  Little help please.  Thanks

[image: Organizer Crashes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was related to a couple of updated agreements in itunesconnect Agreements, Tax, and Banking.  After I got those agreements accepted, the next day the latest version and build and crashes appeared in Xcode.  Thanks for watching.

Comment: hey @jeff, thanks for your kind information . but can you please discibe how do i find that certificate and how can i accept that